# Using == in Strings

Tags: java, string

I have a small question

I have created this:
String abc="abc";
String xyz=abc;

```
if (xyz==abc){
 System.out.println("true");
}
```

And the output is "true" as expected because the Strings, Objects, are point to the same memory position, right?
But, if I have this:

```
String abc="abc";
String xyz=abc;
abc = "acvb";
System.out.println(abc + " " + xyz);
if (xyz==abc){
 System.out.println("true");
}
```

The output is "false" (it doesn't appear). Does this mean that changing the value of a String create a new memory position and points towards it, the String that was changed, (unlike the arrays)?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps some pictures will make it clear, although my reliance on ASCII art to do the pictures may reduce the clarity somewhat...

Any time you have an object, a variable (or parameter) of that object really holds a "reference" or "pointer" to the object, not the object's value.  A `String` is an object in Java, but this answer really applies to any kind of object.  I've sometimes explained it this way: Think of an object as a house, and a reference is a piece of paper with the address of the house written on it.  If you make a copy of the reference, you're creating a new piece of paper, but it has the same address written on it.  So there's still just one house.

So here's the situation after each line of code:

```
String abc="abc";

variable abc 
     |
     |
     v
---------------
|    abc      |   (String object.)
---------------
```

Now:

```
String xyz=abc;
```

You're copying the *reference*, so now you have two variables pointing to the same object:

```
variable abc   variable xyz 
     |               |
     |     +---------+
     v     v
---------------
|    abc      |   (String object.)
---------------
```

These two variables point to the same object, but *they are still two separate variables*.  So if you change the variable `abc`, it has no effect on `xyz`, which still is a reference to the same object.  That is, after this:

```
abc = "acvb";

               variable xyz        variable abc
                     |                  |
           +---------+                  |
           v                            v
---------------                  ----------------
|    abc      |                  |    acvb      |
---------------                  ----------------
```

So now, `abc==xyz` is false because they're not pointing at the same object.

Answer (score 3):

> Does this mean that changing the value of a String create a new memory position and points towards it,

The `String abc` is a reference to an object.  The reference can be changed in this case, and you are pointing it to a new object when you use `=`.  However when you say

> the String that was changed,

You have to be clear and distinguish that only the reference to the `String` has changed.  None of the String objects have changed, they are immutable.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to understand is that a `String` is an **object** and when you use `==` to compare **object references** you are comparing **addresses**, not **values**.  If you have two `String` references `aString` and `bString` and compare them with `bool theyAreEqual = aString == bString;`, `theyAreEqual` will be `true` **only** if `aString` and `bString` are referencing the *exact same* `String` object.

If `aString` and `bString` reference two different `String` objects with identical (or different) contents then the result will be `false`.  (And when you say something like `abc = "acvb";` you have assigned a new object to the reference `abc`.)